# Is malloc() in kernel space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I know that `kmalloc()` can replace `malloc()` on kernel space. Many people think that the `malloc()` can not run in kernel space; however, I found this definition at`linux-4.9.6/include/linux/decompress/mm.h`

```
static void *malloc(int size)
{
    void *p;

    if (size < 0)
        return NULL;
    if (!malloc_ptr)
        malloc_ptr = free_mem_ptr;

    malloc_ptr = (malloc_ptr + 3) & ~3;     /* Align */

    p = (void *)malloc_ptr;
    malloc_ptr += size;

    if (free_mem_end_ptr && malloc_ptr >= free_mem_end_ptr)
        return NULL;

    malloc_count++;
    return p;
}
```

Does it mean that we can use `malloc()` on kernel level?

Comment: It's not for general kernel usage. The file header tells you exactly what it is for: "Memory management for pre-boot and ramdisk uncompressors".

Comment: Read the function and figure out if it's suitable as a general purpose malloc replacement.

Answer (score 3):

In a word: No.

The comment that precedes that code explains what it is for:

```
 * Memory management for pre-boot and ramdisk uncompressors
```

This code is only used very early in system initialization, before `kmalloc()` is available. (Possibly even before the code for it has been decompressed!) It is incredibly limited -- it cannot* free memory -- so it can only be used on a very small scale.

If you need to allocate memory in the kernel, you must use a function from the `kmalloc()` family.

---

*: While there is an implementation of `free()` paired with this `malloc()`, it can only free memory under one very specific circumstance: when every single allocated block has been freed.